# Is there a way to add multiple CSS classes to the backdropClass property of a mat-dialog?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

Attempt something like this but doesn't seems to work on angular 8

```
const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
dialogConfig.backdropClass = 'display-after-delay backdrop-background';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can add multiple classes to the backdrop by passing in an array of strings as shown in the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogConfig):

> `backdropClass: string | string[]`
>
> Custom class for the backdrop.

So you should write your code like below:

For adding a single class:

```
const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
dialogConfig.backdropClass = '<your-single-class>';
```

For adding multiple classes:

```
const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
dialogConfig.backdropClass = ['display-after-delay', 'backdrop-background'];
```